# SharePoint 2013 - WebPart - PeoplePicker not in CodeBehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm working on a SharePoint 2013 WebPart. Here I'm using the standard peoplePicker-Element based on

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

When I create the Element on the ascx page..

```
<SharePoint:PeopleEditor ID="peopleEditor" runat="server"  Rows="1" IsValid="true" AllowTypeIn="true" MultiSelect="True"
            PlaceButtonsUnderEntityEditor="False" />
```

Intellisense recognizes the element fine.. but not in the code behind. Here I'm getting a notification about potential missing assemblies.. but as I think everything is fine here to..

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
```

I do not have a single clue what the problem is.. Hope for your help.
And thanks in forcast.

Greetz
Iki

Answer (score 0):

Ok Sorry.. My fault.. I deployed the soltion SandBox-Mode ... For the future.. You need to have a Fram-Deployement if you want to use peoplePicker..